# ASP.NET application to communicate with Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, ldap

I am working on an asp.net application where it communicates with the Active Directory. Sometimes i need to create a security group or sometimes to create and import the users so it is not a good idea to play with the Active Directory that is running in office. I'm looking for a way that i could work in office and work with a stand alone Active Directory on my system. Below could be a idea but i don't know how to do it.

- Virtual Machine with Windows server on host computer. (but frankly I'm not sure I can communicate from my local host to the AD of guest computer)

Please if anyone has a better idea let me know.